# In JavaScript/AngularJS, I can't seem to remove the "T" in a date field from the DB?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I must be missing something very obvious, but I could use help. I have an Angular web app, which is getting data from a MS Web API. The DTO object has two date fields. When those fields come in, there is a "T" in the date field.

e.g. 2017-05-01T03:43:55

For whatever reason, I can't seem to get rid of that darn "T" when using the date. I'd tried using a date format both on the calendar control that displays the date data, and using the JavaScript format() command. I also tried using the Javascript replace() command to replace the "T" with a space. And I tried using Moment.js to create a new date (which seems to fail and give me an invalid date).

```
var startDate = moment(badge.startDate).format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
var startDate = badge.startDate.format(''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'');
var startDate = moment(badge.startDate).replace('T',' ');
```

What am I missing? How should I be doing this? As far as I can tell, any of these should work?

Comment: Have you tried `moment(badge.startDate.replace('T',' '));`

Comment: Can you specify the error? What is the invalid date?

Comment: Phix - that and another small change seems to have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate filter for that as below.

```
  return (input) ? $filter('date')("2017-05-01T03:43:55", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") : '';
```

You can change for of date according to your requirements. You can see details Below.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

**use, don't build what already exists!**
First visit [moment js](http://momentjs.com) this component is very helpful and has many options which you can do with a date.

```
var date = moment(yourDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

> format has a lot of options, you can find it on moment js documents.